# Installing indicator-sysmonitor says unable to locate package

Tags: package-management, software-installation, system-monitor

In Ubuntu 22.04, I run

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
```

but get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package indicator-sysmonitor
```

I have added both repositories via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexeftimie/ppa` and `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor`, and ran `sudo apt update` but I still get an "unable to find" error. Any ideas?

Comment: PPAs are release-specific. The "unable to find" result means that there is no available version that is compatible with your release of Ubuntu.

Comment: The first ppa has not been updated in 503 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be located as the PPA has not been update for Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish.

It can be installed by [downloading](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor/) the .deb (click the green link on the right of that page) and running it with Software Installer.

[image]